# Kendall tau: Kendall Score

Tags: r, machine-learning, ranking, kendall-tau

Currently, I am working with with Kendall tau distance between two rankings. I get a `tau` value of `0.849`, `Z` (statistical significance of `3.9`) and a `Kendall score` of `56`. What does this Kendall score tell us about? Here under are my results and I would appreciate if anyone could enlighten me with these values of `S, D` and `varS` - if they are worthy of adding to a research evaluation. Or is only the `kendall tau` and `Z` are enough to tell the story?

```
kendal$s
    [1] 56
    attr(,"Csingle")
    [1] TRUE
kendal$D
[1] 66.00001
attr(,"Csingle")
[1] TRUE
>
kendal$varS
[1] 212.6667
attr(,"Csingle")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/mcleod/2003/DBeirness/MannKendall.pdf

Comment: I have read it but it doesn't say much about the values. For example, is 56 as Kendall's score a good value or not? that's what i wanted to know

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this "Kendall score" is only an intermediate step in the computation of τ (the Kendall correlation) and not of any substantive interest itself. There's no need to report it. Focus on the τ.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the data so that one variable is in order (call it $A$) then take each value of $B$ except the rightmost and count how many values of $B$ to the right of it are larger (call it $p$) and smaller (call it $q$). The add up all the $p$ and call it $P$ and similarly to form $Q$. Then $S = P - Q$. Whether that has any meaning in your scientific question is up to you. It is a way of defining the way in which Kendall decided to measure correlation. $S$ also plays a fundamental role in many other so-called non-parametric tests.